# Joomla - mistakenly getting "Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet"

Tags: joomla, authentication

I have a Joomla 3.2.3 site and simply the strangest thing is happening. The Super Administrator is all fine. Many of the Registered users are all fine. However, a couple of Administrators cannot login to either the back or front end (and they were able to a couple of months ago). I've verified 100 times that the user name and pwd are correct and have even created a new user and set his privileges to Administrator and regardless of what I do, when I try to login, I get the error message which is simply not correct in this case.

"Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet."

My guess is that this is something quite specific to my setup, so if you don't immediately know the answer, can you please suggest ways to debug it? I honestly don't know where to start with this one. I already look at the database tables (i.e., verifying things such as user_group_map are correct) to see if I could find something different about the users that can login and the users that can't and I've come up empty.

Can someone tell me what other criteria has to be met, that somehow these users are failing?

Comment: So this was  a site you updated? Also did the registered users self register?  Are you using any separate registration/user management system?

Comment: >...site you updated? 
Yes.  I've updated it numerous times as each Joomla version became available.  I have no idea if one update is the one that caused the problem.
>...did the registered users ...
At some point, yes.  Something has happened to previously working users.
>...using any separate...
Registration is Joomla core and I JTag member directory system.  That may very well be the issue, however the major question still remains - what criteria does the Joomla login look at?  If I find that out I can figure out what's causing it.

Comment: Joomla has updated its password hashing to use more modern methods by default. This is seamless for everything that is coded using the core APIs. If you are using anything that expects the old style hashing and  is not coded with the core APIS you may need to make adjustments. I would check with the JTag people and see if they have issued a fix.

Comment: Sorry, I was supposed to say @Elin in the previous comment.

Comment: @Elin - how would that explain why most of my users, including me as the Super Admin, can log in without issue?

Comment: Super Admins are always a bit weird but I'm wondering if somehow whatever handling the user handling is doing something unusual for people who have admin login.  Can you look in the database at the stored passwords and see if the beginning letters are the same for each group? That will tell you if they are being hashed differently.

Comment: @Elin - The passwords for the users that cannot login both start with $P$D.  I also took a working user and went into the Joomla User Manager and changed his password and now his password starts with $P$PD and he can no longer login.  I have a suspicion that this has something to do with the security/password changes in 3.2.1, however even after reading several posts on this, I'm at a loss for what do or how I got in this mess :(

Comment: @Elin - In regards to your question about JTag, I did ask them and the denied any connection.  In their defense I disabled it and disable Ajax Register and the problem still exists.

Comment: Okay that's the problem.   The password type is getting converted to the wrong type on save. What is the prefix before it gets changed? ALso what is the prefix for a new user? Also what php version do you have?

Comment: @Elin - PHP version is 5.4.26.  The passwords for the users that work don't really have a rhyme or reason, other than that they all start with a number (e.g., 036ee85f5b5a39...).  The password of any new user created start with the dreaded "$P$D".

Comment: And can those new users get in?

Comment: @Elin - No, no new users can get in.

Comment: Ok I'm not sure what the exact problem is because they have made some changes that clearly created some problems. The first thing i that you have 5.4 which is good and means you can support strong passwords an won't have any problems when they raise the base level.   Second the problem is that there is a disconnect between how your passwords are being stored and how the authentication plugin is trying to decrypt. Try going to the authentication/joomla plugin and saving. I think that may reset your options so that they are consistent.

Comment: Wait new users CAN or CANNOT get in?

Comment: @Elin - New Users added through either the Admin User Manager or through the Front End UI User Registration process CANNOT login.  As for your suggestion, I'm not sure if it's what you meant, but here's what I did.  I went into Admin Extensions and found the "Authentication - Joomla" plugin, opened it and saved it.  I then created a new user via the Admin UI and am still not able to login and the password still starts with $P$D.

Comment: Right but can that user login in? The issue is not the hashing it is that the plugin is looking for the wrong hash (at least that is what is sounds like to me).

Comment: @Elin - No user that is created or even saved via the Admin UI at this point will be able to login, period.  I have to believe that at some point I received a partial update or something that has left me hanging, but not knowing what code to check has me completely at a loss.  I'd be even happy to reapply 3.2.3 if you think that had a snowball's chance in hell of succeeding.

Comment: You could try that, it wouldn't hurt. Basically there is a disconnect, the user create is using one hashing while the authentication is using a different hashing, probably the old one. In the 3.2 update there was an option to upgrade to the new format, but now it's required for everyone. This is why I asked about if you were using another plugin because the plugin should be matching the user registration/update but it's not. I have not really studied how the 3.2.1 change from the opt in system was implemented but since you are an update, I think you may have been caught in the transition.

Comment: @Elin - Well, go figure. I guess I could've saved both of us a lot of time by just trying the ol' manual installation first.  I just took the files from 3.2.3 and copied them over what I have and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

So for all the folks playing at home, the answer was to manually re(over) install Joomla 3.2.3.  As much as I enjoy using Joomla, many of the 3.x upgrades were not 100% functional even though they appeared to be. Hopefully all the kinks will be worked out soon.